# How to use iCloud for photo backup

Tags: photos

On my IPad i have 1300 photos and small movies so I desperately need more free space on it. My computer is being repaired theese days, and I normally keep all pictures on an extern harddisc - that is not possible to use at the moment due to my broken computer.

I now made a 'safety-update' of the Ipad including photos, to my ICloud.
1) How can I check that the photos are on ICloud by now...?
2) Can I safely delte the photos on my IPad, being abel to acces and (somehow) copy them to my computer and then to my extern harddisk later, Wien my computer is back in business...?

Tank you SO much for

Answer (score 1):

Photo Stream only saves the last 1000 photos and doesn't include videos. An iPad backup to iCloud doesn't include photos or videos. That tells me it is not safe for you to delete anything at the moment.

I think your best bet is to install one of the other cloud services that support syncing photos. Both Dropbox and SugarSync can do backups although Dropbox renames all your photos so SugarSync might be a better choice. There are other services as well but these are the two I happen to use the most.

Comment: They are also only retained for 30 days. More information Photo Stream can be found here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4486

Comment: THANK you Bill - good to know. I'll try sugarSync - did'nt hear about it before now...